# How to fix output for a simple shell

Tags: c, linux, shell, fork, execvp

My shell program is currently accepting the ls commmand but is returning the wrong output.  The other issue I've noticed is my shell is not deleting the pervious line entered.  When I type ls it does return my files, but then if I type ls again the shell still has my previous command saved.

My output: Needs [* cmd *] before (exitstatus) and should not have [ -a ]

```
shell> ls -a
[ ls ] [ -a ] (PID: 1101501) //pid's will be different
.  ..  Exec  Exec.c  Shell  Shell.c  String  StringMalloc.c //content will be different
(Exit: 0)
```

Expected output:

```
shell> ls -a
[ ls ] (PID: 3052378)
.             Descr.c                       MallocLab
..            Dest.txt                      Midterm.txt
a             Dir                           Notes
...
[* ls *] (Exit: 0)
```

Code:

```
    const int MAXLINE = 80;
    const int MAX_ARGS = 5;
    char buffer[MAXLINE];
    char* args[MAX_ARGS];
    char* p;
    int i = 0;
    pid_t pid;
    int arg;
while(1)
    {
        printf("shell> ");
        if(!fgets(buffer, MAXLINE, stdin)){break;}
        p = strtok(buffer, " ,\n");
        while(p != NULL)
        {
            args[i] = p;
            p = strtok (NULL, " ,\n");
            ++i;
        }
        args[i] = NULL;

        arg = i;
        for(i = 0; i < arg; ++i)
        {
            printf("[ %s ] ", args[i]);
        }
        printf("(PID: %d)\n", getpid());
        

        for(i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); ++i)  /*I'm assuming the line deleting is in here*/
        {
            if(buffer[i] == '\n')
            {
                buffer[i] = '\0';
            }
        }

        pid = fork();

        if(pid == 0)
        {
            int ret = execvp(args[0], args); 
            if(ret < 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "exec error (%s) -- exiting\n",
                    strerror (errno));
                exit (1);
            }
        }

        if(pid > 0)
        {
            wait(NULL);
            fprintf("[* %s *] ", args);  /*not sure how to get [* cmd *] in output*/
            fprintf("(Exit: %d)\n", errno);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The difference between the actual and expected output is unclear. Obviously they are different but it is unclear what incorrect aspects you are trying to point out. Why is the first output wrong?

Comment: One error is that `i` is not reset to `0` for each loop iteration.

Comment: My output should have [* cmd *] before (exitstatus) and should not have [ -a ] after the ls command.

Comment: That's totally unclear from the output. The first output shows the command entered is `ls -a`. So why would it be expected to not have `[ -a ]`? Doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: `fprintf("[* %s *] ", args);` -> `fprintf(stdout, "[* %s *] ", args[0]);` ? Don't your compiler tell you `warning: casting a char * to FILE *` or something like that? Listen to wranings - `fprintf` is not `printf`.

Comment: surpirsingly not, I thought that was an error that wouldn't allow me to compile but it kept returning 0 and allowing me to run the ./shell @KamilCuk.

Comment: @kaylum, I don't want to keep track of the flags only the command

Comment: If you don't want the flags then remove the `while(p != NULL)` loop which is the very code that extracts the flags. Just have `args[0] = strtok(buffer, " ,\n");` which extracts only the command. Confused about why you add code that you don't want.

Comment: I'm sorry if its confusing but I want the flags to be used, I don't want the flags to be returned in the output. So if I type {"ls", "-l"}  I want that flag to be used, but I only want the user to see the command {"ls"} in the output.

Comment: Then remove the `for(i = 0; i < arg; ++i)` loop which is printing everything and replace it with code that prints only the first arg: `printf("[ %s ]\n", args[0]);` If you run your code in a debugger or even step thru it on paper line by line you should be able to see the lines of code that print the unwanted output.

Comment: Thank you for the help! It compiled and worked.